# Auto indent turns off itself automatically on php files

Tags: indentation, filetype-php

I don't get it, my vimrc has `set ai`, but when editing project files (php), `:set ai?` always returns `noautoindent`

inside .vimrc `:set ai?` returns true.

my rc:

```
" vim-plug (https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)
" Automatically install vim-plug and run PlugInstall if vim-plug not found

if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall | source $MYVIMRC
endif

"*****************************************************************************
"" Plug install packages
"*****************************************************************************

" Specify a directory for plugins
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'tyrannicaltoucan/vim-quantum' " let g:quantum_black = 1
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'
Plug 'editorconfig/editorconfig-vim'
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'valloric/matchtagalways' " doesn't work properly in neovim, cursor jumps about
Plug 'ap/vim-buftabline'
Plug 'ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

"*****************************************************************************
"" Visual Settings
"*****************************************************************************

set number
set ruler
set nowrap

if $TERM_PROGRAM =~ "iTerm"
  set termguicolors
endif

let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"

let g:quantum_black = 1
colorscheme quantum

"*****************************************************************************
"" NERDTree config
"*****************************************************************************

let NERDTreeShowHidden = 1
let NERDTreeIgnore=['.git$[[dir]]', '.swp']

map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

"*****************************************************************************
"" Optimizations
"*****************************************************************************

set lazyredraw

let g:python_host_skip_check = 1
let g:python3_host_skip_check = 1

"*****************************************************************************
"" syntastic
"*****************************************************************************

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

"*****************************************************************************
"" yank and cut to osx clipboard
"*****************************************************************************

noremap YY "+y<CR>
noremap XX "+x<CR>

"*****************************************************************************
"" indent
"*****************************************************************************

" tabs
set listchars=tab:˗\ ,eol:¬
set list

" spaces
let g:indentLine_enabled = 1
let g:indentLine_concealcursor = 0
let g:indentLine_char = '·'
let g:indentLine_faster = 1

set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2

set ai

filetype plugin indent on

" make < > indents keep selection
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv

"*****************************************************************************
"" matchtagalways
"*****************************************************************************

let g:mta_filetypes = { 'html' : 1, 'xhtml' : 1, 'xml' : 1, 'jinja' : 1, 'php': 1 }

"*****************************************************************************
"" ctrlp
"*****************************************************************************

set wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git,*.rbc,*.pyc,__pycache__
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\v[\/](node_modules|target|dist)|(\.(swp|tox|ico|git|hg|svn))$'



"*****************************************************************************
"" buffers
"*****************************************************************************

noremap <Tab> :bnext<CR>
noremap <S-Tab> :bprevious<CR>

noremap <C-w> :bd<CR>

"*****************************************************************************
"" general
"*****************************************************************************

set autoread
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" :h last-position-jump
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of vim's internal php settings. If you look in `vim##/indent/php.vim`, there's the following line:

```
setlocal noautoindent
```

If you want to override this feature, you'll need to use an autocmd in your `vimrc`. Try this:

```
autocmd FileType php setlocal autoindent
```

This will turn on auto indenting whenever vim detects it's editing a php file. Alternatively if you want to *always* have autoindenting, you could also do this:

```
autocmd BufReadPost * setlocal autoindent
```

This will turn on auto indenting whenever vim open *any* file.

It's probably worth noting that if they specifcally turned off `autoindent` they may have a good reason for it. But this is how you would change it if you wanted to.

For more info see `:h autocmd`

Comment: Since the BufReadPost event occurs before the FileType event, I think that the BufReadPost autocommand may not work as it will be followed by the sourcing of the indent/php.vim file. (I have not tested that.) It might be better to use `autocmd FileType * setlocal autoindent` instead. It is true that that will not be triggered if the `filetype` is not set, but in that case, no filetype plugins will be sourced to mess up your preferred `autoindent` setting, either.

Comment: wait that makes no sense. how I see: vim comes php-indent script, this script disables system `ai` in favor of its own implementation. So the problem is that `indent/php.vim` doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @salivan You didn't actually ask about php indenting though. You specifically asked what was switching off the `autoindent` option. You'll need to update your question if your problem is actually with how Vim's default PHP indenting works. (Or better, write a new one, which would avoid moving the goalposts after Tumbler41 has already answered)

Answer (score 2):

The general mechanism for discovering where a particular Vim option was set is the `:verbose` command:

```
:verbose set autoindent?
```

The above will inform you that autoindent was most recently unset by the script in location `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/php.vim`

@Tumbler41 has already described [how to overrule this with an autocommand](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11024/343), but I'll note that Vim also has more specific mechanisms for altering settings made by a global filetype plugin, which are described in `:help ftplugin-overrule`.

In your case, the third method is the the best one to use:

Create a file in the location `~/.vim/after/indent/php.vim` with the contents:

```
setlocal autoindent
```

Comment: thx for `:verbose set autoindent?` this is useful