# vim doesn't auto indent php files with html in it

Tags: indentation, filetype-php

In relation to this question: [Auto indent turns off itself automatically on php files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/auto-indent-turns-off-itself-automatically-on-php-files)

Vim has a php auto indent script; it behaves in following way: When `autoindent` is ON - if you open a php script, it disables default `autoindent` and uses its own logic. But I noticed that if the php file contains escaped html this script stops working. And auto indentation and autocomplete is not working.

Can you confirm that this is indeed so? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce, but I'm also not exactly sure what you're looking for. I have a file `test.php` that I've put a couple of lines of html in. When I enter the file and do `verbose set ai?` I get `noautoindent    Last set from ...indent/php.vim`. So the script seems to be working for me. Can you be a little more specific about what's not working and what the expected behavior is?

Comment: @Tumbler41 open a php file that only contains PHP code. `verbose set ai?` will return `noautoindent` BUT - indentation will still happen because php.vim takes over indenting. Now open file with mixed content, see php.vim indentation breaks!

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a few more details about how indentation is broken. Maybe an example of what it does/what you're expecting it to do?

Comment: Yes, if you could provide an [MCVE](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/how-to-create-a-minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example), that would be very helpful.

Comment: @all, the indent is being controlled by `indentexpr=GetPhpIndent()`, which doesn't look it handles HTML